# SOQL Find all Permission Sets with a given Custom Permission

Tags: soql, query, permission-sets, custom-permission

How to get all permission set has a custom permission.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? As written, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I understand this. Why was it downthumbed? This helped me. Finding a Custom Permission in a permission set can be like a needle in a haystack.

Comment: that's why I haven't deleted this question, I know someone will benefit from it one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ParentId FROM SetupEntityAccess
WHERE SetupEntityId IN (SELECT Id FROM CustomPermission WHERE DeveloperName ='yourCustomPermissionAPIName')

SELECT Name FROM PermissionSet where Id=:permissionSetIds
```

to get debug logs

```
Set<Id> permissionSetIds = new Set<Id>();
for (SetupEntityAccess access : 
    [SELECT ParentId FROM SetupEntityAccess WHERE SetupEntityId IN
               (SELECT Id FROM CustomPermission 
                  WHERE DeveloperName = 'yourCustomPermissionAPIName')]) {
    permissionSetIds.add(access.ParentId);
}
System.debug('--'+permissionSetIds);
for (PermissionSet ps : [SELECT Name FROM PermissionSet where Id=:permissionSetIds]) {
    system.debug(ps.Name);
}
```